# Unable to pass boolean value via ajax call, but the same call works with a rest HTTP client

Tags: jquery, api, rest

I have to pass a Boolean value to a REST API. When I use Advance REST Client (chrome extension) to do it, I am able to pass it. But when I trigger the API through a jQuery Ajax call, the Boolean value is received as a string ("true" or "false"). I am using Rails at the server end.

What is the difference in calling the API via a rest client and via jQuery Ajax? What is the way to overcome it?

I have seen several questions related to this, but there was no satisfactory answer.

Comment: It is not a solution but I think you have to parse the string "true" or "false" to a boolean value on the server side, or, use a integer value and use `1` or `0`.

Comment: @FelipeOriani Wanted to know how is rest client different than an Ajax call. If it can be passed via a rest client then why not Ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. To overcome that issue should use an Object Document Mapper (ODM) tool onto your server side.